# Laravel Dusk - how do I assert who the browser is logged in as?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I have a Laravel system that allows people to authenticate by clicking a url containing a login 'token'. This facilitates convenient access on mobile devices without having to manage passwords.

I have created a model named `App\LoginTokens` and a web.php route:

`Route::get('/arbitraryprefix/{tokenCode}','LoginTokenController@loginWithTokenAndRedirect')`

This controller method validates the token, and if valid, logs the user in using `\Auth::loginUsingId($loginToken->user_id)` and redirects to the token's url `$loginToken->url`.

There is obvously other security measures (including token expiry and rules to ensure the user being authenicated is of one specific class that does not have much access in the system.

I am writing some test cases in Laravel Dusk, and want to check that the token logs the person in as the correct user.

My system in on Laravel 5.4 so I use `assertPathIs` as `assertUrlIs` in not avaialble in 5.4, and this confirms I redirect to the correct document.

```
            $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($loginToken,$oneClientUser) {
                $browser->visit('/logout')
                ->waitForText('Login')
                ->visit($loginToken->getLoginAndRedirectUrl())
                ->waitForText($oneClientUser->name)// the users name shows in top right when they are logged in.
                ->assertPathIs(parse_url($loginToken->url,PHP_URL_PATH))
                ->visit('/logout')
                ->waitForText('Login');
            });
```

I want to chain onto the browser a call like

`$browser->assertUserIs($oneClientUser)`

but I have had to settle for checking for their user name, which is displayed for authenticated users.

Is there a way to verify which user I am authenticated as in a `$this->browse(function($browser){ --here--})` callback?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: `assertAuthenticatedAs()`

```php
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use App\User;

class AuthTestExample extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    protected $user

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create(['password' => bcrypt('password')]);
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) { $browser->logout(); });
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testLogin()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->assertGuest()
                    ->visit('/login')
                    ->type('@login', $this->user->login)
                    ->type('@password', 'password')
                    ->click('@login-button')
                    ->assertPathIs('/dashboard')
                    ->assertAuthenticatedAs($this->user);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks IGP, this sounds like exactly what I was looking for BUT it does not work... I included ->assertAuthenticatedAs($oneClientUser) chained after my ->assertPathIs call and it returns "The currently authenticated user is not who was expected.", and it says ist is comparting NULL with my $oneClientUser.

Comment: You can pass a second argument to `assertAuthenticatedAs`. The guard. Maybe that's what's missing.

Comment: The guard 2nd parameter is optional, defaults to NULL, but I agree with you - may need to pass it in, as it in used: $response = $this->visit("/_dusk/user/{$guard}"); in the currentUserInfo method in the InteractsWithAuthentication trait. I'll look tomorrow